# Fatal Error occurring while passing html data in array using simple html dom php

Tags: php, html, arrays, simple-html-dom

I am trying to extract data using simple html dom and it works fine when i am passing html file or url to it i-e :-

```
$html = file_get_html('sv.html');
$foo = $html->find('p[plaintext^=EDUCATION AND TRAINING]');
$items3 = array();
 foreach ($pinfo as $keypi) {
    # code...
    //var_dump($key);
    //print_r($key);


    while ( $keypi->nextSibling() ) {
        if ( $keypi->nextSibling() == TRUE) {
            //echo $key->nextSibling();

         $keypi = $keypi->nextSibling();
            $varcpi = $keypi->plaintext;
            //$cnt++;
    //echo "cnt=$cnt<br><br><br>";

        }
        if ( trim($varcpi) == "JOB APPLIED FOR" ){
            break;
        }
        $items3[] = $varcpi;
}
}
$trimmedArray = array_map('trim', $items3);
 $b = array_values(array_filter($trimmedArray));
 var_dump($b);
```

Problem occurs when i pass html file in array as i am trying to pass it html data that was converted from pdf using  **PDFTOHTML** (a php library) in code given below **$page** contains html data if i **echo $page** it's showing html accurate but when i pass it as array to **simple html dom** it's not working :-

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

 $pdf = new \TonchikTm\PdfToHtml\Pdf('cv.pdf', [
     'pdftohtml_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdftohtml.exe',
    'pdfinfo_path' => 'C:/wamp64/www/new/poppler-0.51/bin/pdfinfo.exe'
]);

 foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {

    $my_array[] = $page . '<br/>';

    }
    //$html = file_get_html('sv.html');
    $pinfo = $my_array->find('p[plaintext^=PERSONAL INFORMATION]');
```

where $my_array[] contains html data is and showing accurate results but when i pass it to simple html dom here :-

```
  $pinfo = $my_array->find('p[plaintext^=PERSONAL INFORMATION]');
```

instead of this:-

```
 $html = file_get_html('sv.html');
```

it shows error :-

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on array in C:\wamp64\www\new\upload.php on line 56
```

i have tried using **str_get_html** which does not any error but also it's not showing any results :-

```
 foreach ($pdf->getHtml()->getAllPages() as $page) {

$html = str_get_html($page);

$pinfo = $html->find('p[plaintext^=PERSONAL INFORMATION]');
$items3 = array();
 foreach ($pinfo as $keypi) {
    # code...
    //var_dump($key);
    //print_r($key);


    while ( $keypi->nextSibling() ) {
        if ( $keypi->nextSibling() == TRUE) {
            //echo $key->nextSibling();

         $keypi = $keypi->nextSibling();
            $varcpi = $keypi->plaintext;
            //$cnt++;
    //echo "cnt=$cnt<br><br><br>";

        }
        if ( trim($varcpi) == "JOB APPLIED FOR" ){
            break;
        }
        // echo $varc;
        $items3[] = $varcpi;
}
}
$trimmedArray = array_map('trim', $items3);
 $b = array_values(array_filter($trimmedArray));
 var_dump($b);
}
```

Output:-

```
C:\wamp64\www\new\upload.php:81:
array (size=0)
  empty
C:\wamp64\www\new\upload.php:81:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

It would be great if anyone help me out here!!!

Comment: Well, like the error says, you're trying to "Call to a member function find() on array". `$my_array` is an array, not an object that you can call a function on. You can call that function on `$html` because `file_get_html` returns an object.

Comment: @GregSchmidt can you help me with that by posting code?

Comment: I can't give you a solution, because you haven't provided enough context. But a quick Google search indicates that there's a function like `file_get_html` called `str_get_html` which will return a DOM object created from the HTML in a string instead of a file. You'll want to somehow pass your `$my_array` data into that function, and then you can call `->find` on the result of that. But `$my_array` is an array, not a string, so you'll need to do that call in a loop or change your data structure.

Comment: @GregSchmidt i'av tried using str_get_html but still have not got any results, the thing i am trying to do is on runtime take a pdf file and convert it on html and then get specific data from it using simple htm dom and everything seems to work fine excepts extracting data from html as i am unable to pass data  to simple html dom, i really need some help here i can post code if you want me to?
Thanks :)

Comment: Posting the code that's not working is a good way to get help, yes. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @GregSchmidt i have updated the post with code check it.

Comment: Your loop structure looks sound. Have you checked that `$page` is actually HTML? (I'm not at all familiar with the class you're using for PDF to HTML conversion, so I don't know what those functions might return.) Have you checked that `$html` is of the format you expect? Have you confirmed that `$items3` is empty, and it's not a problem with the array manipulations after that causing `$b` to be empty?

Comment: @GregSchmidt yes i have checked everything that you have mentioned

Comment: Well, looks like this is just a case then of working through the debugging on your side. You seem to have some good debugging commenting out in there (though referencing `$key` instead of `$keypi`). Put some of that back in, dump variables at all the stages to make sure that they look like you expect them to. When you find the thing that doesn't look like you expect, then you can hopefully see what's gone wrong in that specific step.

Comment: i have found the problem @GregSchmidt ,problem is in html that i have mentioned here, See this maybe u might be of any help thanks :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49968544/finding-plaintext-that-contains-nbsp-using-simple-html-dom